# Limit And Continuity of $f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix} x^{2} ; x \in \mathbb{Q} & \\ 0 ; x \not\in \mathbb{Q} & \end{matrix}\right.$

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, epsilon-delta

I am having difficulty in the following function

$f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
x^{2} ; x \in \mathbb{Q}  & \\ 
0 ; x  \not\in  \mathbb{Q} & 
\end{matrix}\right.$

I have following fundamental doubts.

1) Does this function have limit at all rational number including zero?

2) Is this function continuous at every rational number?

Thanks

Comment: The  function has limit only for $x\to 0$. To show that it hasn't limit everywhere else you need the fact that in every interval there are rational and irrational numbers, and I don't think that it can be proved with Higher Secondary School maths.

Comment: Please suggest any method you want.

Comment: @ajotatxe I think the fact "every interval contains rational and irrational numbers" can be proven with methods accessible to a secondary student. First prove there is an irrational between any two rationals, then demonstrate there are two rationals in any interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**

Let $r \ne 0 $ be a rational .

considere two sequences

$$r_n=r+\frac 1n \;\; ( \in \Bbb Q)$$
and
$$y_n=r+\frac{\pi}{n} \;\; ( \notin \Bbb Q)$$

both converge to $r$
but

$$f(r_n)=r^2+\frac 1n(\frac 1n+2r)$$
goes to $ r^2\ne 0$

and

$$f(y_n)=0$$
goes to $0$.
we conclude that
$$\lim_{x\to r}f(x) \text{ does not exist}.$$
$f$ is then not continuous at $r$.

For $r=0$, observe that

$$(\forall x\in \Bbb R) \;\; |f(x)|\le x^2$$
thus

$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0=f(0)$$
and
$f$ is continuous at $0$.